# Salt minion failolver keeps trying to connect to first server

Tags: high-availability, salt-stack

I'm trying to create a Salt multi-master enviorment, but I've noticed that the minion tries to connect to same master all the time and only tries the second master after the timeout. I've even tried to configure master_suffle and random_master but always tries the same master...

My configuration is:

```
id: server-id
master:
  - salt-master01
  - salt-master02
master_type: failover
random_master: True
master_shuffle: True

master_alive_interval: 10
retry_dns: 0

color: True
yaml_utf8: True
verify_master_pubkey_sign: True
always_verify_signature: True
master_sign_key_name: master_sign
```

And my minion version is 2016.11.6 Carbon.

I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/highavailability/index.html#multimaster-with-failover) document it's mentioned that `master_type: failover` will make minion to connect to the first available master from the list. Though `master_shuffle: True` should make minion to pick-up first master randomly, my understanding is that once minion was able to connect to the master - it will store state this master will become the *first* for the minon. This means that minion will try to reconnect to this master again as long as it's available.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that during my tests I've stopped a master and the minions always tried to connect to that master because is the first on the list (salt-master01), so both options are beign ignored because the minion don't shuffle the masters and when one master fails ti don't try to connect to the other until it get the timeout from first (it don't keep that master as failed).